# Rooted Android does not execute all commands programatically

Tags: android, exec, android-4.2-jelly-bean, su

This code below successfully reboots the Android device:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

    OutputStream outputStream = p.getOutputStream();
    InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("reboot");
    dataOutputStream.flush();
    dataOutputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
            p.waitFor();
```

This code is supposed to stop a currently running app. But it does nothing.

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

        OutputStream outputStream = p.getOutputStream();
        InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("am force-stop com.XXX.XXX.XXX");
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        dataOutputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        p.waitFor();
```

All the commands work via ADB Shell, and the device has the "su" script.
Is there a process I can troubleshoot? What should I do?

When dataOutputStream.flush() is run it gives me this error:

04-29 01:56:05.057: W/System.err(6969): java.io.SyncFailedException: fsync failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)

Comment: what is your question? what is the problem you are running into?

Comment: The second set of code doesn't work, but the first one does? Any insight to why?

Comment: "Doesn't work" could mean anything, be specific.

Comment: Added system error, and doesn't work means it doesn't do anything. But the same command from ADB will work.

Answer (score 0):

use try-catch surround  write-flush

```
try{
 dataOutputStream.writeBytes("am force-stop com.XXX.XXX.XXX");
 dataOutputStream.flush();
}catch(IOException e){
}
```

Unaffected the exec result !